# SQL Server Management Studio Version Controlling

Tags: sql-server, ssms

As I know if I need to use some kind of version control I need to use 3rd party softwares.

Is there any built in version controlling option in the SQL Server management studio ?

Comment: Do you mean version control for the data inside your database?

Comment: TFS will be there i think and it will come In built in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: do you mean version control on the objects (stored procedures, functions, triggers)?

Comment: RedGate has a nice product; https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not any version control. You should to use 3rd party tools.

Comment: This is the only answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to version control the database schema, you could use SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) along with the version control system of your choice.  Although not technically part of SSMS, SSDT is based on the same Visual Studio shell as SSMS so the interface is similar.

SSDT is included with the latest version of Visual Studio 2015, including the free Community Edition.  For a vendor database, you could start by reverse engineering the existing database using the SSDT schema compare tool.

Comment: He's asking for built in and not 3rd party

Comment: @DanAndrews, taken literally that is true but perhaps not if the tool is from the same vendor.